# javascript problems with jquery thrown in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope this isnt a repeat below is my problem javascript

```
function aaaaa() {
  var sid = documentGetElementById('placeholder').value;
  var nancy = documentGetElementById('luckroll').value;
   if (sid >= nancy) {
      $('#pageLuckSucceed').slideDown();
   } else {
         $('#pageLuckFail').slideDown();
   }
}
```

placeholder is supplied from session storage on page load and luckroll from a random number generator both of these are working and writing numbers to the dom, the problem is the javascript will only slideDown one or the other no matter whether  sid is greater or not than nancy , ie; all results give pagelucksucced or all results give pageluck fail if this a simple solve please forgive me as i am teaching myself javascript and i have got hung up on this problem , been all over the internet and nothing seems to work, Thanks in advance, Morph

right here we go again, copy and paste this time

```
function zzzzz() {
    diceRoller();
    myFunction();
}


var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(aaaaa, 3000);
}

function diceRoller() {
    var dice = {
        sides: 11,
        roll: function () {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 2;
            return randomNumber;
        }
    }

    function printNumber(number) {
        var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
        placeholder.innerHTML = number;
    }
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.onclick = function () {
        var result = dice.roll();
        printNumber(result);
    };

}

var jonny = document.getElementById('luckRollPage5');

function aaaaa() {
    var sid = placeholder;
    var nancy = jonny;
    if (sid >= nancy) {
        $('#pageLuckSucceed').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('#pageLuckFail').slideDown();
    }
}
```

the first function zzzzz is fired from an onclick function, then the myFunction event giving the aaaaa function after three second gap, the relevant section of html is this

```
<p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your Luck</td>
                    <td id="luckRollPage5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your Roll</td>
                    <td id="placeholder"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>


        <p id="page5LuckSucceed"><span class="firstcharacter">Y</span>ou are Lucky <a href="185.html" onclick="return CreateSession();"><img src="images/button%20(1).png" alt="Click Here"></a></p>

        <p id="page5LuckFail"><span class="firstcharacter">Y</span>ou are Unlucky <a href="395.html" onclick="return CreateSession();"><img src="images/button%20(1).png" alt="Click Here"></a></p>


    </div>
```

would parseFloat help and if so where would I put it

once again thanks in advance

Right here we go agin lol i have the following javascript which is showing the the correct numbers when I console log the variables

```
function aaaaa() {
var sid = document.GetElementById('placeholder').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
var nancy = document.GetElementById('luckRollPage5').innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
if (sid>= nancy) {
$('page5LuckSucceed').slideDown();
} else {
$('page5LuckFail').slideDown();
}
}
```

the html it is affecting is this

```
<p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Luck</td>
                <td id="luckRollPage5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Roll</td>
                <td id="placeholder"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>


    <p id="page5LuckSucceed"><span class="firstcharacter">Y</span>ou are Lucky <a href="185.html" onclick="return CreateSession();"><img src="images/button%20(1).png" alt="Click Here"></a></p>

    <p id="page5LuckFail"><span class="firstcharacter">Y</span>ou are Unlucky <a href="395.html" onclick="return CreateSession();"><img src="images/button%20(1).png" alt="Click Here"></a></p>


</div>
```

I always get one answer nevermind what the random number generator creates for the sid variable, the nancy variable is created on page load

Comment: Use `Document.getElementById()` instead of `documentGetElementById`.

Comment: How did you manage to write `documentGetElementById`?

Comment: Can you console.log your values after they've been set?  after they've been defined, try `console.log(sid); console.log(nancy);` to see if they're the values you're expecting and as shown in your DOM

Comment: you may also want to parse the values into whatever they are (ints or floats) if they are not strings, otherwise your if might not evaluate as you intend

Comment: sorry typo on my behalf i did use document.getElementById()

Comment: just tried console.log in chrome and i get uncaught referenceerror: .....is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: there must be a name in the reference error informing what is not defined.

Comment: afternoon techie, can you look at my last message at the bottom of the page and see if you can shed some light, Thanks

Comment: can somebody look at the last sections in the first post where I have posted what appears to be almost working script

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure sid and nancy are getting the proper values?

Try using `document.getElementById` instead of documentGetElementById

```
function aaaaa() {
  var sid = document.getElementById('placeholder').value;
  var nancy = document.getElementById('luckroll').value;
   if (sid >= nancy) {
      $('#pageLuckSucceed').slideDown();
   } else {
         $('#pageLuckFail').slideDown();
   }
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: yeah i typoed my fault i am using it as in your post but it appears they are not getting the values but i dont understand why not everything is spelt correct and referenced correct or so it seems

Comment: Can you paste your HTML as well?  Also know that the function `aaaaa()` will need to be run *AFTER* the `placeholder value` and `luckroll value` has been set in the DOM.  It sounds like your code may be trying to get the values in the DOM _BEFORE_ the numbers are written to the dom.

Comment: the luckroll value is in place when the page loads set from a sessionstorage item I will now post my javascript as im home and can copy and paste, this is the script

Comment: I have reposted my javascript and the piece of html it refers to in the first post please check my work, thanks friends

Comment: Hello again it appears that it IS working but only works once and then returns the same result every time the onclick event that triggers the zzzzz function, is this normal behaviour and if so can i change this behaviour, thanks again

Comment: Is it the onclick that is returning the same result?  Can you console.log(result) after this line and see what returns?: `var result = dice.roll();`

Comment: thanks for the help magneticmagnum, I maybe away from my pc for a couple of days I will let you know as soon as I'm back

Comment: magnetic, i have edited my longer javascript i have posted to show where i am now, console log on result gives the correct number  7, the other two variables are giving me the following in console.log

Comment: <td id="placeholder">7</td> and the equivalent in my other  element <td id="luckRollPage5">10</td>

Comment: can somebody look at the last sections in the first post where I have posted what appears to be almost working script